# Block javascript execution from css

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, xss

When adding the below style attribute on a popular website in IE7 emulator nothing happened, but when I execute it from a trivial website in IE7 emulator it does get executed.

```
<body style="width: expression(alert())">
```

How can you prevent the expression from being executed?

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent that from executing in IE 7, or how to prevent it from executing in browsers that are still supported?

Comment: ie7 is long dead from microsoft perspective.

Comment: Is this really an XSS problem? Would you allow your site's users to edit its styles?

Comment: @user3553031 I would also like to know what security measures can be taken for today supported browsers please.

@/DanielA.White It's more about how the problem is solved than the problem itself.

@/nnnnnn I would never let users do that, but I would like to know what to add so that if someone did it, we're safe

Answer (score 1):

As a mitigation against JavaScript being injected in unexpected places in *modern* browsers, use a [content security policy](https://content-security-policy.com/). For instance, a CSP of `script-src: none;` will deny all JavaScript execution within your page, regardless of where it originated.  More nuanced policies can be designed to allow JavaScript only from specific URIs, or only scripts with specific hashes.

Comment: This is good for XSS, but here the malcious code comes from 'self'. But it's a good resource, thank you!

Comment: You can deny JavaScript execution from `self` or allow only scripts with known hashes; this is a good practice for XSS prevention in general.

Comment: This will not prevent `HTC` nor `expression` to be executed since it only works from IE11. But I agree it is a good first level of defense! Does your Javascript code gets executed when you deny javascript execution from `self` or is the `self` option for a JSF app?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are talking about is called [`Dynamic Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(v=vs.85).aspx) and is no longer supported as of IE8.

> Dynamic properties (also called "CSS expressions") are no longer supported in Internet Explorer 8 and later, in IE8 Standards mode and higher. This decision was made for standards compliance, browser performance, and security reasons. Dynamic properties are still available in Internet Explorer 8 in either IE7 mode or IE5 mode. (For more information about document compatibility modes, see Defining Document Compatibility.) Because Internet Explorer 8 in IE8 mode is fully compliant with the Cascading Style Sheets, Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS2.1) standard, most dynamic properties written to work around Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)-related shortcomings in previous versions of Internet Explorer should no longer be needed. Other dynamic properties with more specific uses can generally be replaced with standard JavaScript.

Comment: So how does this answer the question about how it works or how to prevent it in IE7?

Comment: I know it's not supported and deprecated, I want to know how they fixed this 5 years ago. Because that kind of issue still exist with HTC until IE9